# Multithreading + Ruby arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, multithreading

I find it hard to understand if it is safe to insert to array in Ruby with multiple threads.

As far as I understand Ruby arrays, just like any other objects are not thread safe. But does it mean that insertion to array is also not safe?

For instance, I have the following code:

```
arr=[]
threads = []

for i in 1..5
    threads << Thread.new do
        for j in 1..1000
            arr << ((1000 * i) + j)
        end
    end
end

threads.each(&:join)

puts arr.length
```

It just spins 5 threads that each pushes 1000 numbers to an array. It seems that the result is always consistent and I always get result of 5000 elements in the array.

So is it safe to do it like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As far as I understand Ruby arrays, just like any other objects are not thread safe. But does it mean that insertion to array is also not safe?

Right. Array insertions are not safe on Ruby, but if you run your code in MRI, it's going to work every time because GIL. GIL (global interpreter lock) was made to prevent this kind of issues, but JRuby and Rubinius does not have GIL and works as you expect (some times produce 5000, some times less).

This is because with GIL only one thread is active at time and because that, there is no problem adding you elements to the array.

Read [this](http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/8085491-nobody-understands-the-gil).

Answer (score 4):

It *might* appear to be thread safe on your machine, but it's not thread safe. When running this on JRuby on a machine with four physical cores, eight threads you'll get different results. A few runs here averaged around 4982 entries.

Two core machines are often less likely to exhibit threading problems than four core ones because the four core systems have more independent caches that can diverge. That makes operations that are coincidentally atomic on systems with fewer caches suddenly unpredictable. Intel's CPUs have an L1/L2 cache pair per core, plus an L3 cache shared by all cores.

Generally you should not be manipulating the same object from multiple threads unless you're using a Mutex for locking, or the object is expressly described as thread safe, such as is the case with [Queue](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Queue.html).

Comment: "four core systems have two independent caches that can diverge" on what weird architecture would that be? If you have two x86 cores with hyperthreading you'd have four logical threads with two l2 caches but that's it. Two real cores on most normal architectures will each have a small local cache and a larger shared cache.

Comment: It could be a historical design that's since been dropped but I'd read about the early i7 architecture being two dual-core designs fused together and sharing an L3 cache. I've adjusted the phrasing here to reflect some more research. I've seen threading problems like this that are impossible to reproduce on a dual-core i7 but which are impossible to avoid on a quad-core i7 of the same generation.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I will have to use Mutex... Really tried to avoid that...

Comment: There's no way around locking if you've got multiple threads operating on the same objects, it's just how you avoid issues like this. It's the same reason there's signals on train tracks: If you have more than one train you need control.

Comment: @tadman Nehalems did habe a shared l3 cache, but it's shared by every core. On x86 the shared cache makes the requires cache coherency implementation just that much simpler and it scales well to the number of cores we're talking about so that's what they're sticking with for now. Having more cores just makes conflicts quadratically more likely which is why you'd see it much more often with four than two

Comment: @Voo That must be the problem here, that it's a probabilistic thing where the likelihood of an event jumps exponentially with each additional cache.

Answer (score 0):

Because each of you threads is pushing 1000 elements into the array..

```
threads.each(&:join)
```

and the `join` call on a `thread` waits for that `thread` to finish it's `block`. What you're actually trying to do is calling `join` on each `thread` so the program waits for each thread to sequentially complete its execution.

But since the arrays in ruby are not `Thread Safe`. So this code has quite an unpredictable outcome, when your system is very busy or has very little cache memory. You can try pushing complex objects inside this array to see the difference.